# How can I make this method more Scalalicious

Tags: scala, recursion, idioms

I have a function that calculates the left and right node values for some collection of treeNodes given a simple node.id, node.parentId association. It's very simple and works well enough...but, well, I am wondering if there is a more idiomatic approach. Specifically is there a way to track the left/right values without using some externally tracked value but still keep the tasty recursion.

```
/* 
 * A tree node
 */
case class TreeNode(val id:String, val parentId: String){
    var left: Int = 0
    var right: Int = 0
}

/* 
 * a method to compute the left/right node values 
 */
def walktree(node: TreeNode) = {
    /* 
     * increment state for the inner function 
     */
    var c = 0

    /*
     * A method to set the increment state
     */
    def increment = { c+=1; c } // poo

    /* 
     * the tasty inner method
     * treeNodes is a List[TreeNode]
     */
    def walk(node: TreeNode): Unit = {
      node.left = increment

      /* 
       * recurse on all direct descendants 
       */
      treeNodes filter( _.parentId == node.id) foreach (walk(_))

      node.right = increment
    }

    walk(node)
}

walktree(someRootNode)
```

Edit - 
The list of nodes is taken from a database. Pulling the nodes into a proper tree would take too much time. I am pulling a flat list into memory and all I have is an association via node id's as pertains to parents and children.

Adding left/right node values allows me to get a snapshop of all children (and childrens children) with a single SQL query.

The calculation needs to run very quickly in order to maintain data integrity should parent-child associations change (which they do very frequently).

In addition to using the awesome Scala collections I've also boosted speed by using parallel processing for some pre/post filtering on the tree nodes. I wanted to find a more idiomatic way of tracking the left/right node values. After looking at the answer from @dhg it got even better. Using groupBy instead of a filter turns the algorithm (mostly?) linear instead of quadtratic!

```
val treeNodeMap = treeNodes.groupBy(_.parentId).withDefaultValue(Nil)

def walktree(node: TreeNode) = {
    def walk(node: TreeNode, counter: Int): Int = {
        node.left = counter 
        node.right = 
          treeNodeMap(node.id) 
          .foldLeft(counter+1) {
            (result, curnode) => walk(curnode, result) + 1
        }
        node.right
    }
    walk(node,1)
}
```

Comment: Where is `treeNodes` defined?  Is there some reason you're not defining TreeNode recursively?  What is the point of `walktree`?  To re-number the `left` and `right` values?  Why aren't the `left` and `right` values associated with `TreeNode`s?

Comment: This isn't codereview, but you need _way_ fewer comments, and you need at least one useful comment.  Exactly zero of your comments say anything relevant that the code does not already tell you.  Throw them all away, and add perhaps two lines describing the goal.

Comment: @Rex, I had the same thought :-)

Comment: treeNodes is just a List of TreeNode. It isn't defined recursively as the list is pulled from a database and that takes time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code appears to be calculating an in-order traversal numbering.

I think what you want to make your code better is a `fold` that carries the current value downward and passes the updated value upward.  Note that it might also be worth it to do a `treeNodes.groupBy(_.parentId)` before `walktree` to prevent you from calling `treeNodes.filter(...)` every time you call `walk`.

```
val treeNodes = List(TreeNode("1","0"),TreeNode("2","1"),TreeNode("3","1"))

val treeNodeMap = treeNodes.groupBy(_.parentId).withDefaultValue(Nil)

def walktree2(node: TreeNode) = {
  def walk(node: TreeNode, c: Int): Int = {
    node.left = c
    val newC = 
      treeNodeMap(node.id)         // get the children without filtering
        .foldLeft(c+1)((c, child) => walk(child, c) + 1)
    node.right = newC
    newC
  }

  walk(node, 1)
}
```

And it produces the same result:

```
scala> walktree2(TreeNode("0","-1"))
scala> treeNodes.map(n => "(%s,%s)".format(n.left,n.right))
res32: List[String] = List((2,7), (3,4), (5,6))
```

---

That said, I would completely rewrite your code as follows:

```
case class TreeNode(        // class is now immutable; `walktree` returns a new tree
  id: String,
  value: Int,               // value to be set during `walktree` 
  left: Option[TreeNode],   // recursively-defined structure
  right: Option[TreeNode])  //   makes traversal much simpler

def walktree(node: TreeNode) = {
  def walk(nodeOption: Option[TreeNode], c: Int): (Option[TreeNode], Int) = {
    nodeOption match {
      case None => (None, c)  // if this child doesn't exist, do nothing
      case Some(node) =>      // if this child exists, recursively walk
        val (newLeft, cLeft) = walk(node.left, c)        // walk the left side
        val newC = cLeft + 1                             // update the value
        val (newRight, cRight) = walk(node.right, newC)  // walk the right side
        (Some(TreeNode(node.id, newC, newLeft, newRight)), cRight)
    }
  }

  walk(Some(node), 0)._1
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
walktree(
  TreeNode("1", -1,
    Some(TreeNode("2", -1,
      Some(TreeNode("3", -1, None, None)),
      Some(TreeNode("4", -1, None, None)))),
    Some(TreeNode("5", -1, None, None))))
```

To produce:

```
Some(TreeNode(1,4,
  Some(TreeNode(2,2,
    Some(TreeNode(3,1,None,None)),
    Some(TreeNode(4,3,None,None)))),
  Some(TreeNode(5,5,None,None))))
```

Comment: +1 for understanding what was desired well enough to find a solution

Comment: It's actually better than gold. This drops a good half a second off the node walk! Thanks!

Comment: @Neil, That's because in your version `treeNodes.filter(...)` has to run through every node every time `walk` is called to find the children.  In my version, a node knows exactly where its children are, and calls them directly.

Comment: I mean for the filter version using foldLeft. If I assemble the tree into a node structure off the bat I would have less need for the tree walk (I'd probably be keeping track whilst assembling the nodes). The filter is necessary as I just have a flat in memory list that is taken from, and will be persisted to, a database.

Comment: @Neil, I added a `groupBy` that prevents you from having to `filter` every time you call `walk`.

Comment: Thanks @dhg. I have not come across groupBy before (I have seen a foldLeft but didn't quite grasp what it was doing). I shall definitely check that out.

Comment: wow. groupBy. Just _wow_. I started out with a 20 minute operation (mostly IO bound and Java badness) and now have something operating in less than 3/10 of a second. Color me gobsmacked.

Comment: @Neil, Great!  Basically your original way was traversing all N nodes N times.  If you do the grouping upfront, you only traverse the N nodes twice.  Also, don't forget to accept an answer for each question you ask.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your algorithm correctly:

```
def walktree(node: TreeNode, c: Int): Int = {
    node.left = c

    val c2 = treeNodes.filter(_.parentId == node.id).foldLeft(c + 1) { 
        (cur, n) => walktree(n, cur)
    }

    node.right = c2 + 1
    c2 + 2
}

walktree(new TreeNode("", ""), 0)
```

Off-by-one errors are likely to occur.

Few random thoughts (better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com):

- try posting that compiles... We have to guess that is a sequence of `TreeNode`:
- `val` is implicit for `case` classes:

  ```
  case class TreeNode(val id: String, val parentId: String) {
  ```
- Avoid explicit `=` and `Unit` for `Unit` functions:

  ```
  def walktree(node: TreeNode) = {
  def walk(node: TreeNode): Unit = {
  ```
- Methods with side-effects should have `()`:

  ```
  def increment = {c += 1; c}
  ```
- This is terribly slow, consider storing list of children in the actual node:

  ```
  treeNodes filter (_.parentId == node.id) foreach (walk(_))
  ```
- More concice syntax would be `treeNodes foreach walk`:

  ```
  treeNodes foreach (walk(_))
  ```